# the type name path is hidden by a static variable

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
struct type1
{
    struct type2
    {

    };
    int tyep2; // No conflic with real type name path: type1::type2
};

struct type4
{
    struct type5
    {

    };
    static int type5; // No conflic with real type name path: type4::type5

};

int type4::type5;  // this path name is equal to type name path: struct type4::type5  


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    type1::type2 var1; // is ok
    type4::type5 Var2; // is ok
    type4::type5 = 0; // is ok, but the static variable has obscured my type 
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1. why the static variable ***type5*** hides the type
   ***type4::type5***
2. Why the compiler does not generate an error when I declare ***type5*** variable?
3. Where I can read about this behaviour in the C++ standard specification? Please post eventually an extract

Comment: Sorry I posted a wrong code

Comment: Why do you say "The static variable has obscured your type"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is ill-formed because of name ambiguity (ignoring the misspelled "tyep" you have scattered around)

> **§ 10.2 Member name lookup**
>
> Member name lookup determines the meaning of a name (id-expression) in a class scope (3.3.7). Name
> lookup can result in an ambiguity, in which case the program is ill-formed. For an id-expression, name
> lookup begins in the class scope of this; for a qualified-id, name lookup begins in the scope of the nestedname-
> specifier. Name lookup takes place before access control (3.4, Clause 11).

Don't do this:

```
struct type5
{
   //...
};
static int type5;
```

Unsurprisingly, this doesn't compile for me on ideone. [Live Demo](http://ideone.com/A7t5O1)

Comment: Thanks for your comment and posting. 
I did not understand why I received negative comments after correcting my code.

Comment: @AngeloDM: My guess is because your question is admittedly something that beginner programmers learn; don't give two things the same name. You specifically asked for a mention in the standard, so I answered with that, but the idea is that I shouldn't have needed to.

Answer (score 0):

1) t**YE**p5 != type5

2) the same reason